# Apache2 doesn't automatically find the index page

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Apache2 doesn't automatically find the index page. 
If I go to the (IP) address -I haven't bought a domain yet- where i should find the index page i receive the Server not found error.

I reinstalled Apache2 after a `apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils` but it doesn't change.
If I go to http://ipaddress/index.html it works.
I have the same problem with all index pages (or install.php pages for exaple).

There's no httpd.conf only apache2.conf and 000-default.conf in site-available.

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with mysql,php7.2 and apache2 installed.

Comment: lets see your `.htaccess` or vhosts config

Comment: Look at `httpd.conf` and check for or add a `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm`

Answer (score 1):

Create an `.htaccess` file or add this string to your `.htaccess` file. This will tell to apache what file is the default index of your website.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Or you can add this lines to your `httpd.conf` file

```
<Directory /yourapp>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</Directory>
```

Comment: As OP seems to have full access to Apache doing this in the `httpd.conf` file would be more efficient

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, I've edited the answer to add the httpd.conf solution

Comment: I would suggest `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>` and not in the <Directory ....>` would make it global rather than specific to one directory

Comment: Then of course we should also check that the `LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so` extension is activated as well